# Understanding a table bloat query

Tags: postgresql

When researching table bloat there is this query that crops up in quite a few places.

[From what i can see its basically been copy pasted since 2008](https://web.archive.org/web/20080603000756/http://pgsql.tapoueh.org/site/html/news/20080131.bloat.html)

I'm struggling to decipher this query so as not to blindly rely on it.

What is so special about the 27 or 23 here and the difference between a windows and non-windows install to offer the values 4 or 8 ?

> CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(v,12,3) IN ('8.0','8.1','8.2') THEN 27 ELSE 23
> END AS hdr,
> CASE WHEN v ~ 'mingw32' THEN 8 ELSE 4 END AS ma

Can anyone offer any insights into this query ?

Would using pgstattuple be a more sensible approach to calculating table bloat ?

Thanks.

```
SELECT  
      tablename AS relname, schemaname,  
      (ROUND((CASE WHEN otta=0 THEN 0.0 ELSE sml.relpages::FLOAT/otta END)::NUMERIC,1))::BIGINT AS tbloat,  
      (CASE WHEN relpages < otta THEN 0 ELSE bs*(sml.relpages-otta)::BIGINT END)::BIGINT AS wastedbytes  
    FROM (  
      SELECT  
        schemaname, tablename, cc.reltuples, cc.relpages, bs,  
        CEIL((cc.reltuples*((datahdr+ma-  
          (CASE WHEN datahdr%ma=0 THEN ma ELSE datahdr%ma END))+nullhdr2+4))/(bs-20::FLOAT)) AS otta  
      FROM (  
        SELECT  
          ma,bs,schemaname,tablename,  
          (datawidth+(hdr+ma-(CASE WHEN hdr%ma=0 THEN ma ELSE hdr%ma END)))::NUMERIC AS datahdr,  
          (maxfracsum*(nullhdr+ma-(CASE WHEN nullhdr%ma=0 THEN ma ELSE nullhdr%ma END))) AS nullhdr2  
        FROM (  
          SELECT  
            schemaname, tablename, hdr, ma, bs,  
            SUM((1-null_frac)*avg_width) AS datawidth,  
            MAX(null_frac) AS maxfracsum,  
            hdr+(  
              SELECT 1+COUNT(*)/8  
              FROM pg_stats s2  
              WHERE null_frac<>0 AND s2.schemaname = s.schemaname AND s2.tablename = s.tablename  
            ) AS nullhdr  
          FROM pg_stats s, (  
            SELECT  
              (SELECT current_setting('block_size')::NUMERIC) AS bs,  
              CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(v,12,3) IN ('8.0','8.1','8.2') THEN 27 ELSE 23 END AS hdr,  
              CASE WHEN v ~ 'mingw32' THEN 8 ELSE 4 END AS ma  
            FROM (SELECT version() AS v) AS foo  
          ) AS constants  
          GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5  
        ) AS foo  
      ) AS rs  
      JOIN pg_class cc ON cc.relname = rs.tablename  
      JOIN pg_namespace nn ON cc.relnamespace = nn.oid AND nn.nspname = rs.schemaname AND nn.nspname <> 'information_schema'  
    ) AS sml  
    WHERE schemaname != 'pg_catalog'
    order by 4 desc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fragment you wonder about uses the version of the database:

```
... FROM (SELECT version() AS v)
```

The query produces different results depending on the PostgreSQL version.

My experiences with that query are mixed. Sometimes it comes up with a good guess, sometimes it is wrong.

I recommend that you don't use it. Monitor the storage size of the database, and if you notice unusual growth, use `pgstattuple` to find out the actual bloat of suspicious tables.

Answer (score 1):

27 and 23 are the number of bytes used by each row header in different versions of PostgreSQL.  There is nothing "special" about them, other than being the correct answers to "how many bytes are used by the per-row headers in  version of PostgreSQL".  I admire the attention to detail, but if the difference between 27 and 23 makes any  difference to the conclusions drawn, I think you are paying too much attention to your belly button lint.

"ma" is for memory alignment.  mingw32 is a specific compiler for compiling on Windows.  It is not the only one used on Windows, and in fact is pretty darn rare anymore as far as I can tell (Visual C++ being quite common).  Pretty much any 64 bit system will have 8 byte alignment, a fact which would be picked up if you used newer versions of the query.  If you want a more up to date version, you should probably get it from the [horses mouth](https://github.com/bucardo/check_postgres/blob/master/check_postgres.pl).

pgstattuple is much slower but more accurate as it actually inspects each tuple, rather than relying on the statistics collection system.  But as far as I am concerned, none of this makes much sense unless you already think you might have a problem with bloat.